# "Do you guys break up?" or "Have you guys just broken up?" Which one is better?

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, present-tense

This [site](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-simple-use.html) says:

> 4: We can also use the present simple for short actions that are
>   happening now. The actions are so short that they are finished almost
>   as soon as you've said the sentence. This is often used with sports
>   commentary, or in demonstrations.
>
> *He takes the ball, he runs down the wing, and he scores!*
>
> *First I put some butter in the pan and turn on the cooker.*

Here is a scene in a movie.

A: We should end our relationship here

B: Fine

C-a friend of both A & B, has just passed by & says: **Do you guys break up?**

A, B & C are Americans

So, does the sentence **Do you guys break up?** fall into the above use of simple present tense (The actions are so short that they are finished almost
as soon as you've said the sentence)?

But I would say it is better if C says: **Have you guys just broken up?** to mention something that has just happened.

So, "**Do you guys break up?**" or "**Have you guys just broken up?**" Which one is better?

Comment: This would be a question for the learning English site.  ("Do you guys break up?" is meaningless and wrong.)

Comment: @JoeBlow, i heard it in the movie StarTrek Beyond

Comment: Hey Tom, (a) you heard it wrong (b) it was deliberately "Yoda-speak" (if you see what I mean) or (c) some other factor is at play.  It's meaningless.  Just forget it - no more interesting than a typo.

Comment: {There could be some very subtle "twisted-English" comedic meaning, such as: "Is the nature of your relationship such that you actually never breakup though you seemingly often breakup" .. or whatever .. but it's just irrelevant.  Anyway it's a question for the learning English site.}

Comment: @JoeBlow, maybe "You guys break up huh"

Comment: Hey Tom, (a) you heard it wrong (b) it was deliberately "Yoda-speak" (if you see what I mean - so, the character "is Russian" or some such and is talking in broken English) or (c) some other factor is at play. It's meaningless.

Comment: @JoeBlow, it could be "You guys break-up" & "break-up" is a noun

Comment: You should be aware that “Do you” and “Did you” in most varieties of English can both be pronounced [ʤuː]. In this case, it seems almost certain that C actually said, “Did you guys break up?”. The type of simple-present usage described in your quote does not apply here, and as Joe says, “Do you guys break up?” makes little to no sense. It would, at best, be taken as a habitual present: “Is breaking up something you guys tend to do a lot?”, which wouldn’t fit the context of their friend passing by and making a casual remark.

Comment: Hi Tom: I don't know what more to say: as given it is "broken English".  (You know what I mean - like a non-English speaker would say.)  OK?  If you don't believe me, ask someone else.

Comment: "Did you guys just break up" is far more idiomatic (and generally more semantically correct), even when speaking generally in the "continuous present".

Comment: @Tom Was it "You guys break up?" - this is a slang idiom; you might hear it in certain informal contexts but it's not grammatically correct. You should never use such idioms outside of casual speech with people using the same idiom. Definitely not in a formal context or in writing.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye “You guys break up?” is neither slang, nor idiom, nor ungrammatical. Eliding the auxiliary in questions like this is part of [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/47827), which is perfectly grammatical. It is heavily associated with colloquial speech, so your advice that it should not be used in formal contexts is sound; but it violates no rule of grammar in any register—only of style.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - just because the phenomena has a name doesn't mean it's grammatically "correct" in the sense that Tom is asking for. Glottal stops are common in colloquial idioms too, but it would be a poor teacher who told a foreigner to pronounce the word _butter_ as _buddher_.

Comment: @Jimmy You are misunderstanding what _grammatical_ (and _idiom_) means (this is common). The question doesn’t ask about this, either; it simply uses words like ‘better’. There is nothing ungrammatical about conversation deletion, end of story. Formal registers are **not** more ‘grammatically correct’ than colloquial ones. A good teacher will tell you what register a certain phenomenon/usage is associated with and when you should and shouldn’t use it; a bad teacher will equate ‘colloquial’ with ‘ungrammatical’ and leave you with an incomplete knowledge of the language they’re teaching.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  Exactly. You guys break up? Elides the auxiliary verb. By the way, I would like to see PROOF that the movies says it as posted by the OP. I'm not buying it. That said, one can imagine: Do you guys break up every week?

Answer (score 1):

> Did you guys **just** break up?

Is the most common way to ask this if the event is very recent.

> Did you guys break up?

Is how you would ask if the you have no notion or idea of when it may have happened.

> Do you guys break up?

Implies that the couple may break up regularly.

> Have you guys just broken up?

Is a slightly more formal way to phrase the first question.

Answer (score 0):

"Have you guys just broken up" is better. If you say "do you guys break up", it makes it sounds like you're asking them if they do it often, but that wouldn't make sense because break ups just happen once. But even better would be to say "Did you guys break up?"

Comment: “Did you guys break up?” is almost certainly what the character in the film _did_ say.

Comment: What about, "Hey, guys, didn't you break up just now?". Btw, present continuous could be possible, "Are you guys breaking up?"